# Can you write JSON to Snowflake stage?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to stream Elasticsearch data into Snowflake. I am testing a python script which ultimately will be deployed as a cloud function/docker app on AWS. For historical I am using the `scroll` API to write x amount of objects into a string and the string to a file. I've used Snowflake's `PUT file://file.json.gz @stage` but that implies I need to write the file temporary to disk before storing on a stage. I have an insanely large amount of data to pull and am trying to eliminate as many steps as possible. Is there a cheeky way I can write files to the stage directly?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way. I have thought about this also a lot but as you are moving data(files) from one system to other you have to write to a temporary space. You can use temp file concept in python if that helps. Also you can try any 3rd party data pipeline but they are not free as far as I know. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a Snowflake Stage linked to an S3 when you save to your S3, with whatever you decide to use, it will be automatically on your Snowflake Stage, this way, you can just send a COPY INTO command and save a step or two.

In my opinion, it's a simple and handy solution.

if you need the steps, let me know and I'll be glad to post those here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've researched this approach and used boto3 to create the bucket in S3, the pipe in Snowflake with ```auto-ingest=true```, then got the ```notification_channel``` from the ```'''describe pipe {}'''.format(pipe)``` query in Snowflake to create the bucket notification using boto3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use snowpipe. You need to create smaller files continuously and using snowpipe, keep on uploading them. You can use Amazon Kinesis Firehose to manage the batches.
Refer to documentation at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html#continuous-data-loads-i-e-snowpipe-and-file-sizing and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-configure.html